# c# WebApplication save as in directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am working on an ASP.net project and I have a file upload control. I have a folder in my solution called user_uploads. How can I modify the following code in order to save the files in user_uploads when I publish the solution?

```
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\" + fn);
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to do as below get the path of the folder using MapPath and than use that path to save you file ...

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/user_uploads");
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);   
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fn));           
//FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path  + fn);
```

Comment: I would suggest `FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fn));` just to be safe :)

Comment: @EbenRoux - thats true answer is updated now with the same ...thanks for d info